USB camera relative PTZ control does not work on Linux kernel version 5.10.43
I am using an Android 10 device with a Linux kernel version of 5.10.43. I am using the V4L2 framework to control a USB camera. I have noticed that the relative control function of the PTZ of various brands of USB cameras is abnormal. Specifically, when I set a positive speed, the PTZ of the camera can move normally. However, when I set the speed to 0 or a negative value, the PTZ of the camera does not stop, but continues to move. Does anyone know how to fix this, please?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
